# Bad use of eval with option parsing

Tags: bash

I'm trying to better understand how use of `eval` can be evil. I've been reading [BashFAQ/048](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048#Examples_of_good_use_of_eval) and I found the following example I can't wrap my head around: Say we have a script `foo` that does option parsing the following way:

```bash
for i; do
    case $i in
       --test-*)
            shift
            name=${i#--}
            eval "$name=\$name"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Why is the following example code injection?

```
./foo --test-'; ls -l /etc/passwd;x='
```

I thought that with this input, name would become `-'; ls -l /etc/passwd;x='`; at the first parsing of the input, we would have the string `-'; ls -l /etc/passwd;x='=$name` passed to `eval`, which would just throw the error: `bash: eval: -': invalid option`. So how is this example supposed to print detailed information on the `/etc/passwd` file?

Comment: The underlying misunderstanding here -- failing to distinguish the difference between quotes that are syntax and quotes that are data -- is also the primary thing that leads to [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${i#--}` just removes the `--` prefix from `$i`, so the value of `name` is

```
test-; ls -l /etc/passwd;x=
```

When this is substituted into the `eval` argument, you get

```
test-; ls -l /etc/passwd;x==$name
```

`eval` then executes this as a command line. `test-` will get an error because there's no such command. `ls -l /etc/passwd` will execute that command. And `x==$name` sets the variable `x` to `=` followed by the value of `$name`, i.e.

```
=test-; ls -l /etc/passwd;x=
```

Notice that the `'` characters are not included. They're parsed by the original shell when you invoke the `foo` script, not passed literally into the script. So the value of `$i` doesn't contain those quotes and they're not in the command executed by `eval`. This allows the `;` to be treated as a command separator. The quotes are needed in the original command to prevent the `;` from being parsed when calling `foo`.

The easy way to tell what an `eval` command will do is replace `eval` with `echo`. Then it will print the command it would have executed.

Comment: I think what the OP is missing is that the `'`s are parsed by the outer shell as syntax instead of becoming part of the literal data passed to the inner shell on its argument vector. You're _implicitly_ answering this by accurately showing what execution would look like. but it might be worth spelling out why it's correct and that it's not a mistake.

Comment: I didn't even realize that's what they were saying, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I completely forgot that `test` remains after stripping `--`; and yes, I completely forgot that the shell joins `text'more_text'"even_more_text"` together when processing words... thank you!

Comment: @dandan13, ...one thing that's helpful is to make sure your mental model includes everything being turned into an array of C strings for the `exec()` call that starts a new process. Forcing content to be coalesced into that array really makes the quote removal and the decisions about what's syntax vs data obligatory -- someone running `echo "hello world"` expects `["echo", "hello world"]` thus printing `hello world`, not `["echo", "\"hello world\""]` (which would print `"hello world"`, with the quotes included in output), for example.

Comment: @dandan13, ...and having that in your mental model makes things like Python's `sys.argv` make more sense in comparison with the command line they were generated from.